# C# filter an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, observablecollection

I'm trying to filter an ObservableCollection in Xamarin project but have problems.
I have field "Checked" in my model **Names** which returns `true` or `false`. I need to get data where field "Checked" equals `true`.

Current code example.

```
public partial class NewPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Models.Names> items { get; set; }

    public NewPage()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>();
        this.BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
```

I am trying this with:

```
items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>(items.Where(w => w.Checked.Equals("true")))
```

OR

```
items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>(items.Where(w => w.Checked == true))
```

But it both doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: It will work if you put `.ToList()` after your `.Where()`

Comment: @g t Hm, but I still have an error `items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>(items.Where(w => w.Checked == true).ToList())`

**Unhandled Exception**
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source occurred

Comment: try this: `items?.Where(w => w.Checked)?.ToList()`

Comment: @g t This time I have **Unhandled Exception**:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection occurred

Comment: The problem is there are no items checked I guess. Check if there are `Any()` before filtering (also check if there are items at all)

Comment: @FelixD. - No it won't. You would have to rebind after the `.ToList()`.

Comment: I assume you meant `this.BindingContext = items;`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I got this working at my place .. **Only difference** I am calling PropertyChanged after that ..

Comment: Gernerally I would not even reassign that collection. Clear the existing one and readd the filtered items. That keeps ur bindings/events up !

Comment: @FelixD. Sorry, but I still confused here. May I ask to add code example what did you do to make this work.